# How to show shadow on product images ( png image )

Tags: magento-1.9

Working on Magento 1.9 website ( currently running on shared hosting )

I want to show little shadow for the product images (png) on all category and product pages for all the products ( by default )

For example:
[image]

want to show shadow like 2nd image on all the images uploaded
is such possible can anyone please guide ?

Answer (score 0):

This has to be done outside of Magento as it cannot be done with CSS. This is not really a Magento Question.

Get Photoshop and apply proper shadows.